# Rcpp package doesn't include Rcpp_precious_remove

Tags: r, rcpp

I have been trying to create a database and installed the "DBI" package, but I am still facing this error. I reinstalled DBI and RSQLite package, but they don’t seem to work.

```
library("DBI")
con <- dbConnect
(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = ":memory:")
dbListTables(con)
```

Error:

> Error in connection_connect(dbname, loadable.extensions, flags, vfs, extended_types) : function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'

Comment: see this thread https://www.mail-archive.com/rcpp-devel@lists.r-forge.r-project.org/msg10226.html . tldr seems to be update Rcpp

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I had the same problem with another package and the issue was that I was running a recent version of the package compiled against a previous version of `Rcpp`.  As [user20650 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416435/rcpp-package-doesnt-include-rcpp-precious-remove#comment120913142_68416435) in the comment, updating `Rcpp` to 1.0.7 should fix it:

```
install.packages('Rcpp')
```

In RStudio you can also use the `packages` panel to update the packages, as in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Well, `install.packages` didn't solve this problem in my computer, but `update.packages` did. Is there any specific reason as to why this happened?

Comment: well, hard to say, since dealing with packages always involves multiple processes that might fail for different reasons. I wouldn't worry too much about it though...

Comment: @DeBARtha Reading this I suspect that both the calling package, "DBI" in the questioners case, and "Rcpp" both needed to have been included in the install.packages operation, and if you were compiling the packages from source you might have needed to order to be Rcpp first and any dependent package to be later. Dependencies are first sought in the user's libraries, so a more recent version might exist on CRAN or Github or Rforge or BioC. Package authors should ideally  include version numbers if such a dependency exists, but they might not be aware of it.

Answer (score 71):

I had the same problem with the packages: *raster*, *tmap* and *sf*.
Reinstalling the package Rcpp solved the problem:

```
install.packages('Rcpp')
library(Rcpp)
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to restart RStudio afterwards for this to take effect.

Comment: Just adding some info: I had the same problem with the `mapview` package and after re-installing `Rcpp` I didn't need to load it, just `library(mapview)`.