# choroplethr package in R will not load

Tags: r, choroplethr

Loading required package: acs
Loading required package: stringr
Loading required package: XML

Attaching package: ‘acs’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

```
apply
```

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘choroplethr’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'units', details:
call: udunits_init(path)
error: function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘choroplethr’ was built under R version 4.0.5
2: package ‘acs’ was built under R version 4.0.5
3: package ‘XML’ was built under R version 4.0.5

Comment: providing the output of `sessionInfo()` might help to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi Joe Snider! Did you try to update the packages (`update.packages()`), install a new version of Rcpp (`install.packages('Rcpp')`) and restart R?

Answer (score 1):

As @jose pointed out in the comments, this can likely be solved by updating your packages. The error you copied is quite long, but the key part appears to be this:

```
error: function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
```

I am actually the author of choroplethr, and I have no idea what this function is, or why Rcpp is being loaded at all when you load choroplethr. But here we are.

When I paste that error message into DuckDuckGo, the first hit I get is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416435/rcpp-package-doesnt-include-rcpp-precious-remove) stackoverflow question.

There the solution appears to simply be typing:

```
install.packages('Rcpp')
library(Rcpp)
```

I recommend trying that and seeing if it works.

Regardless of whether that alone solves your problem, I also recommend following the other suggestion @jose made. Namely, typing:

```
update.packages()
```

And trying again.

Dependency management in R is a pain. It is probably worth getting into the habit of typing `update.packages()` when you get an error you don't recognize to see if it magically solves your problem.