# Why does running the yearmonth function in the tsibble R package keep giving me Rcpp error?

Tags: r, rcpp, tsibble

When I run the below code, using the tsibble package, I get the error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Month`.
i `Month = yearmonth(Month)`.
x function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
```

I tried reinstalling Rcpp, updating Rcpp, and nothing works yet. Can someone please help with this issue?

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(Rcpp)
library(tsibble)

z <- data.frame(
  Month = c("2019 Jan","2019 Feb","2019 Mar","2019 Apr","2019 May"),
  Observation = c(50,23,34,30,25)
)

z <- as_tibble(z)

z %>%
  mutate(Month = yearmonth(Month)) %>%
  as_tsibble(index = Month)
```

Comment: [Rcpp package doesn't include Rcpp_precious_remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416435/rcpp-package-doesnt-include-rcpp-precious-remove)

Comment: What version of R are you on? You can check the R version with `R.version`. (code runs fine for me, btw)

Comment: As hinted by @Isaiah that is almost surely due to a binary build of `tsibble` against a different version of `Rcpp` than you are running.  Simply upgrading both to what is current at CRAN should fix it.

Comment: I've updated both and it still doesn't work. So the answer may lie in updating my version of R? I

Comment: Looks like tsibble isn't installing on my computer. I'm researching that now

Comment: OK I updated my R version and the above code now works! Thanks!

Comment: OK I updated my R version and it works fine! Thanks Isaiah!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I see this was closed as a duplicate of "Rcpp package doesn't include Rcpp_precious_remove", which has two answers, each of which is `install.packages('Rcpp')`. However, after closure, the OP has tried `install.packages('Rcpp')` which did not work. OP then updated R, which did work, but was not mentioned in "Rcpp package doesn't include Rcpp_precious_remove". Was wondering if this was still a duplication? Perhaps it was not updating R itself, but a sideeffect, such as forcing an update of all packages.

Comment: @Isaiah  You can search about the error message here at SO, and on the mailing lists.  It is exactly as I described (a cross between versions of package depended upon and using --ie compiled with newer, running with older) which affect only users of compiled packages.  None of this had anything to do with R itself but only with partial updates from packages.  And it got long sorted out for everybody using releases made since.  This all happened a while back.